# Waiting for function result

Tags: node.js, sails.js

How should I refactor this code to properly wait for _getWorkerId function and its result?

```
var EventsPersistancyService = {
  accept: function acceptService(msg) {

    function _getAppCategory() {
    }

    function _getWorkerId(user_sid, login) {
      Worker.findByLogin(login, function(res){

      });
    }

    var content = msg.content.toString();
    content = JSON.parse(content);
    content["app_category"] = _getAppCategory();
    content["worker_id"] = _getWorkerId();

    Event.create(content).then(function (x) {});
  }
}
```

Comment: Add callback function as a third argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add callback function as a third argument:

```
function _getWorkerId(user_sid, login, cb) {
    Worker.findByLogin(login, function(res){
        // here process data from res and create `response` variable
        // ...
        cb(response);
    });
}
```

And then you call `_getWorkerId` like this:

```
_getWorkerId(1, "login", function (response){
    content["worker_id"] = response;
});
```

And that's it. It is async approach.

Comment: Its of course change how code looks like. I mean in non-async approach there are 2 functions, next field assignement, and last is making some query (Event.create). Code is easy to read.

Comment: If you want it synchronous you have to got that `findByLogin` function synchronous as well. And it doesn't seem to be as it has a callback in your code.

Comment: @userbb I bet you want your code to be more like C++ - executed line by line. But this is not what JavaScript in general is.

Comment: I am aware of that a async struct looks different, but still I am searching most readable way. Of course line by line is most readable:)

Comment: @userbb There is library called `q`. Maybe it will make things better for you.